# XML CDATA Section

Tags: php, xml, rss

```
$description = $dom->createElement("description");
$descriptionText = $dom->createTextNode($row['description']);
$description->appendChild($descriptionText);
$item->appendChild($description);
```

I concede (again), where do I put the CDATASection for my XML description?  I have played around for hours, am I over complicating this? Help!

Thank you in advance

Stu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but maybe it's http://docs.php.net/domdocument.createcdatasection

```
$descriptionText = $dom->createCDATASection($row['description']);
```

Comment: Well it worked, but the funny thing is I could have sworn I had done that already.... damn and thank you.